How frequently ubuntu OS releases security patches?
I would like to set up automatic patch through patch management tool but there is some dependencies with ubuntu kernel and i can not update directly, have to validate it first and then apply it.
Is there a fixed date for the release of Ubuntu Kernal updates?

Use Kernel Livepatch in Ubuntu Pro if possible. It's free for personal use. Livepatch patches your kernel right away without waiting for a fixed date.

Does this answer your question? Is Canonical Livepatch not supported on non-LTS release like Ubuntu 18.10?

As soon as possible... though if there is a common release date for all OSes to release a non-public aware security/CVE fix, the date will be the common date for all OSes; thus the only set date is fixed for all OSes, and prior notice of the release of the patch is not provided (after all its done on non-public aware discovered flaws; so all OSes can patch at the same day/time)
